# select() does not seem to work on TTY

Tags: c, linux, embedded, serial-port

I'm currently writing a program that needs to communicate with an AT interface over an UART interface (the operating system is Linux). But I'm having trouble using `select()` on the file descriptor. For some reason select does not consider the file descriptor to be ready for reading, but  To narrow down the problem I have used the following program.

```
int main()
{
    char buffer[BSIZE];
    fd_set rfds;
    int ret;
    struct termios cnf;
    struct timeval tv;

    fd = open("/dev/ttyO1", O_RDWR);
    // Have also tried to set fd = 0 for stdin, as a reference
    signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);
    tcgetattr(fd, &cnf);
    old = cnf;
    cfmakeraw(&cnf);
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &cnf);
    while (1) {
        tv.tv_sec = 5;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;
        FD_ZERO(&rfds);
        FD_SET(0, &rfds);
        write(fd, "AT\r", 3);
        ret = select(fd+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        printf("ret = %d\n", ret);
        if (ret < 0) {
            perror("select()");
        }
        else {
            ret = read(fd, buffer, BSIZE-1);
            buffer[ret] = '\0';
            printf("read: \"%s\"\n", buffer);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The run looks something like this

```
    root@linux:~# ./stuff
    ret = 0
    read: "AT
    OK
    "
```

Which indicates that select thinks that there is no data, but when trying to read there is data. This seems very strange to me. Also, I've tried to exchange the tty with stdin, and that works just fine.

The code is being run on Texas Instruments EZSDK PSP kernel, but that shouldn't be the problem. Also, the `stty` settings looks like the following

```
    root@linux:~# stty -aF /dev/ttyO1
    speed 9600 baud; rows 24; columns 80;
    intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
    eol2 = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
    lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
    -parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
    -ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
    -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel
    opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
    isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
    echoctl echoke
```

Have I missed som crucial flag to `open()`? or perhaps need to set some setting using `termios`? Does this method require some special hardware

EDIT:
I get the same problem when trying to run the program `/dev/ttyUSB0`, which also happens to be is an AT interface. Seems to me that it is `tty` related.

changed fd to what I actually used and wondered about.

Comment: Actually, aside from some inconsistencies in the code (fd vs 0, and writing done on stdin, which shouldn't work), it should work, and very likely does. Have you tried running it like this: `echo -ne 'AT\r' |./stuff`? And it should work on a real tty, though (assuming there is something to read from it).

Comment: Yeah, this is just a test application (turns out it does work to write to stdin :D). I've tried running `microcom` on `/dev/ttyO1`, and that works just fine, also reading and writing works just fine as well. The only problem is that `select()` does not seem to react to the incoming data. My guess is that there is some termios setting that is missing.

Comment: Oh, writing to stdin works, you just can't read what you written to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't add file descriptor of serial port to fd set.

Change line:

```
FD_SET(0, &rfds);
```

to:

```
FD_SET(fd, &rfds);
```

Or add the following line, if you need fd zero in the set.

```
FD_SET(fd, &rfds);
```

Comment: Ouch! I really missed that one. That solved it! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be /dev/ttyS1 and not /dev/tty01. You are attempting to select on the VT (virtual terminal) which happens to be attached to the UART in your embedded board, but this is not the same thing,

Comment: When trying to open `/dev/ttyS1`, or any other `ttyS*` for that matter, the `termios` calls does not work (returns error).  And I can't use `microcom` on any of the `ttyS*`. So I'm pretty confident that it should be `/dev/ttyO1`. Is there some place I could learn more about the difference between virtual terminal and ttys?

Comment: That's a 'O' (letter O) rather than 0 (zero).    Linux kernels for TI OMAP - and probably by extension some other spin-off devices such as the Sitara family of devices have hardware serial ports named /dev/ttyO1 and upwards.  (I think fore the sake of sanity they are '1' based)

Comment: @Kotte I see. Then my answer doesn't make sense then. Sorry.