# select() responds to stdin but not to /dev/tty

Tags: c, select, console, termios

This is a very similar question to [select() does not seem to work on TTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986998/) but I don't appear to be making the same mistake with `FD_SET` as the OP there.

On my Linux box (running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for Desktop), I'm trying to read an unbuffered character from the console in both blocking mode (calling `fgetc()` unconditionally) and non-blocking mode (repeatedly asking `select()` whether it is worth calling `fgetc()`).

Both modes work if I'm reading from `stdin`.  However, if I want to explicitly read from the console independent of whether `stdin` has been redirected, my understanding was that I should open `"/dev/tty"` instead.  This also works in blocking mode, but not in non-blocking mode: `select()` keeps returning 0 at the end of each timeout despite frantic key-pressing.  I'm not sure why `stdin` and `/dev/tty` would behave differently in this regard. Their `termios` flags seem the same.

```
$ gcc foo.c

$ ./a.out
c_iflag = 25862
c_oflag = 5
c_cflag = 191
c_lflag = 35387

Well?? 
read character 'g' in blocking mode from stdin

We're waiting... 0 0 
read character 'g' in non-blocking mode from stdin

$ ./a.out /dev/tty
c_iflag = 25862
c_oflag = 5
c_cflag = 191
c_lflag = 35387

Well?? 
read character 'g' in blocking mode from /dev/tty

We're waiting... 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
too slow: read nothing in non-blocking mode from /dev/tty

$ ggggggggggg
```

If I attempt to use `/dev/console` or `/dev/tty0` I just fail with a null `FILE *` from `fopen()`. Here is the source `foo.c`. What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main( int argc, const char * argv[] )
{
    
    const char * name = "stdin";
    FILE * filePointer = stdin;
    int fileDescriptor;
    struct timeval timeout;
    struct termios term;
    fd_set rdset;
    int result, iCycle, nCycles = 10;
    char c;

    if( argc > 1 ) /* open the user-specified file instead of stdin */
    {
        name = argv[ 1 ];
        filePointer = fopen( name, "r" );
    }
    if( !filePointer ) return fprintf( stderr, "failed to open %s", name );
    
    fileDescriptor = fileno( filePointer );

    /* make things unbuffered, non-canonical, non-echoey */
    setvbuf( filePointer, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );
    tcgetattr( fileDescriptor, &term );
    printf("c_iflag = %d\n", term.c_iflag);
    printf("c_oflag = %d\n", term.c_oflag);
    printf("c_cflag = %d\n", term.c_cflag);
    printf("c_lflag = %d\n", term.c_lflag);
    term.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    term.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    tcsetattr( fileDescriptor, TCSANOW, &term );
    
    /* get an unbuffered character (blocking mode) */
    fprintf( stdout, "\nWell?? " );
    fflush( stdout );
    c = fgetc( filePointer );
    fprintf( stdout, "\nread character '%c' in blocking mode from %s\n", c, name );
    fflush( stdout );

    /* get an unbuffered character (non-blocking mode) */
    fprintf( stdout, "\nWe're waiting... " );
    fflush( stdout );
    for( iCycle = 0; iCycle < nCycles; iCycle++ )
    {
        FD_ZERO( &rdset );
        FD_SET( fileDescriptor, &rdset );
        timeout.tv_sec  = 1;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;
        result = select( 1, &rdset, NULL, NULL, &timeout );
        if( result > 0 ) break;
        fprintf( stdout, "%d ", result );
        fflush( stdout );
        if( result > 0 ) break;
    }
    if( iCycle < nCycles )
    {
        c = fgetc( filePointer );
        fprintf( stdout, "\nread character '%c' in non-blocking mode from %s\n", c, name );
        fflush( stdout );
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf( stdout, "\ntoo slow: read nothing in non-blocking mode from %s\n", name );
        fflush( stdout );
    }
    
    /* restore canonicality (avoid having to type `reset` after every run) */
    term.c_lflag |= ICANON;
    term.c_lflag |= ECHO;
    tcsetattr( fileDescriptor, TCSANOW, &term );
    if( filePointer != stdin ) fclose( filePointer );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the first argument to `select()`. `select()` only checks the first `nfds` descriptors in each FD set. Since you specified `1`, it only checks for input on FD 0, and ignored the FD used for `/dev/tty`.

Change it to:

```
select(fileDescriptor+1, &rdset, NULL, NULL, &timeout );
```

Comment: That.... works. So thank you. But I'm confused.  `fileDescriptor`, as far as I understood it, is just a handle whose value (3 in my case) is arbitrary. It's not a count. But you're saying I should use it as a count?  I should ask `select()` to check the first 4 descriptors of a set that, as far as I know, I only added one descriptor to...?   You say it would be checking FD 0... why would FD 0 be in the set?  Again, my understanding must be flawed because I thought FD 0 meant `stdin`, and I don't want it to check `stdin`...

Comment: The first argument has to be higher than the largest FD you want it to check. So if the value is 3, it needs to check at least FDs 0 through 3, so the count has to be 4.

Comment: Even though you've only set 1 FD in the set, it needs to know the maximum FD to look for.